# Flux, how to correctly reuse components?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

still studying Flux, I'm in trouble with some logic about the store.
Let's say I've created a component, a single button that manage a vote, like a switch "Yes"/"No".

So I have my voteButton that manage a voteAction that use a Dispatcher to call a Store function that change the votedByViewer state.

All it's fun and all it's right... if I have a single button.
But if I have multiples, they share the same store and so the re-render happen on all the multiples components.

This is my initial js:

```
// Parse all DIV for React management
$("#be-content [id*=like]").each(function (index) {
    var div_id = $(this).attr("id");

    // Render the VoteButton
    ReactDOM.render(
        <VoteButton />,
        document.getElementById(div_id)
    )
});
```

Each VoteButton is correctly rendered in page but each switch change the state of all the buttons. This is my VoteButton:

```
var voteStore = require('../stores/voteStore') ;
var voteActions = require('../actions/voteActions');

var VoteButton = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            voted: voteStore.getVote()
        }
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        voteStore.addVoteListener(this._onChange);
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function () {
        voteStore.removeVoteListener(this._onChange);
    },
    handleVote: function () {
        this.state.voted ? voteActions.unvote() : voteActions.vote()
    },
    _onChange: function () {
        this.setState({
            voted: voteStore.getVote()
        })
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="link">
                <button onClick={this.handleVote}>{this.state.voted? 'YES':'NO'}</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

module.exports = VoteButton;
```

Any idea on how to solve it? Maybe I have to use Containers?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to set one id for each button you are using. When you click it's passing this id to the action, then dispatcher, then the store receive it.
Your store is an array and each key is a button id. When the store receive the data it changes the needed id. And your button get the state of its id ( getVote('buttonid');)

Comment: So my store, that now is like this var _voteStore = {votedByViewer: false}, should be transformed in an array of key value pair, right? With the functionalitiy to add new item in the array, used during the store initialization. Is this the way?

Comment: yes that's it. It doesn't have to be an array, object is good too, up to you and how you want to do things but you got the point, keeping and id, adding new buttons id in your store, binding the button.

Comment: _voteStore= { button1:false, button2:true ... } for example :)

Comment: Thanks François. In addition have you any idea about how to manage this: now if a _onChange event is triggered, the render function is called for each VoteButton. How to use different instances of the VoteButton component, each one with its own dispatcher and, eventually its own store (oppositely to the array previously said)? In my initial js the VoteButton is a var: var VoteButton= require('../components/VoteButton') ;

Comment: well you can check in your _onChange function is the state has changed and if yes you set the new state if not you do nothing (if(votestore.getvote('id') != this.state.voted) { //update state } Something like that